# ClassCastException when getting the selected item of ListView as string or textview

Tags: java, android

I got **runtime error** exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TwoLineListItem cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
```

My Activity extends Activity **NOT** ListActivity and here is my layout construction:

```
<LinearLayout ...> <ListView ...></ListView> </LinearLayout>
```

**Java:**

```
   ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewXMLdata);
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
        android.R.id.text2, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries));

    lv1.setAdapter(arrAdapter);

    lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {          
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
            lView.getItemAtPosition(position);

            String itemSelected = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked Position Number " + position + ": " + itemSelected ,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();


        }
    });
```

My only main concern is just to get the string (item selected) on my list.

**NOTE 1**: I am not working on any database.

**NOTE 2**: I already tried casting it to CharSequence itemSelected =  ((TextView) view).getText().toString()  but still got runtime error.

The runtime error occurs only when I started to select item on the list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2` has as its root a `TwoLineListItem` widget with two children(two `TextViews`), the two rows of text. Casting this widget to a `TextView` will fail with the exception you see in the `logcat`. Search for the desired `TextView` with `findViewById`:

```
String itemSelected = ((TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2)).getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your ListView is being loaded with TwoLineListItem types and you are tring to cast the View into a TextView in the following line:

```
String itemSelected = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
```

Changing this to something like:

```
String itemSelected = ((TwoLineListItem) view).getText1().getText();
```

should work.

Edit:

The Android documentation at:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html
says:

> **public abstract void onItemClick (AdapterView parent, View view,
>   int position, long id)**
>
> Since: API Level 1 Callback method to be invoked when an item in this
>   AdapterView has been clicked.
>
> Implementers can call getItemAtPosition(position) if they need to
>   access the data associated with the selected item.
>
> Parameters
>
> **parent**    The AdapterView where the click happened.
>
> **view**  The view within the AdapterView that was clicked (this will be a view
>   provided by the adapter)
>
> **position**  The position of the view in the
>   adapter.
>
> **id**    The row id of the item that was clicked.

So, the view passed as parameter to the method is actually a TwoLineListItem, the type you should cast the view to.

Once you get the reference to TwoLineListItem, you can access any of its public members including both TextViews with:

> **public TextView getText1 ()**
>
> Since: API Level 1 Returns a handle to the item with ID text1.
>
> Returns A handle to the item with ID text1.
>
> **public TextView getText2**
>   ()
>
> Since: API Level 1 Returns a handle to the item with ID text2.
>
> Returns A handle to the item with ID text2.

Comment: THanks..your solution helps a lot but this will only get the position (index) of the selected item.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, you can look into `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2`, then you will find the layout xml as follow :

```
    <TwoLineListItem xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:mode="twoLine"
        android:paddingStart="?attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
        android:paddingEnd="?attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd">

        <TextView android:id="@id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem" />

        <TextView android:id="@id/text2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/text1"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/text1"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItemSecondary" />

    </TwoLineListItem>
```

The `TwoLineListItem` has two `TextView`s.
Hope this helps.